# “Moshe, your servant” and “Moshe, your prophet” - why the different wording in prayers?

Tags: tefilla, moshe-rabbeinu, nuschaot

In the preamble to the text of spice offering in Shacharis (nusach Ashkenaz) the text is

כאשר צוית אותם על ידי משה **נביאך**

whereas in Musaf for Rosh Chodesh and Sholosh Regolim the text before the Musaf Korbonos is

כמו שכתבת  עלינו **בתורתיך** על ידי משה **עבדך**

Why does one text refer to the Torah and Moshe, your **servant** and the other refer to Moshe, your **prophet**?

Comment: I would guess there is no preamble to the text of spice offerings in [original] Nusach Ashkenaz. If it got added from Kabbalistic sources, then there's no reason to expect conformity.

Comment: Perhaps   "Mipi kevodecha" is a nevua equivalent, as" binevua", so the question is why not avdecha in ktoret... no?

Comment: Maybe the distinction lies in one being a verbal commandment hence he is referred to in his role as a prophet, and the other is transmission of the Torah, recording it as His servant? Although the recording was done via nevua, perhaps they're different functions. Have to look into it more.